# How to get all elements dynamically without knowing their number

Tags: xml, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have an xml which might have several signatures elements. I don't know the number of signatures elements for each root but I need to group by this element so that I would get one row for each root element.

Do you think it's doable using value method?
I've read ([Getting nth Element from last in a xml in Sql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959754/getting-nth-element-from-last-in-a-xml-in-sql-server)) how to establish the number of elements but one is not allowed to use range in value method.

Here's my code:

```
            declare @xml as xml ='<root>
                <Row>
                    <proceeding>
                        <signatures>XII GU 609/18</signatures>
                        <signatures>XII GUp 392/18</signatures>
                        <commissioner_name></commissioner_name>
                        <court_department>XII Wydział Gospodarczy</court_department>
                        <administrator_function>syndyk</administrator_function>
                        <court_name>Sąd Rejonowy w Gliwicach</court_name>
                        <administrator_name></administrator_name>
                        <commissioner_deputy_name />
                        <administrator_licence_number>920</administrator_licence_number>
                    </proceeding>
                    <msig_entry>
                        <chapter>0</chapter>
                        <issue_date>2019-11-15</issue_date>
                        <url>http://www.imsig.pl/pozycja/2019/221/58729</url>
                        <section>3</section>
                        <sequential_number />
                        <signature>BMSiG-58674/2019</signature>
                        <position_number>58729</position_number>
                        <yearly_number>221</yearly_number>
                    </msig_entry>
                    <id>BMSiG-58674/2019</id>
                    <order>
                        <order_date />
                        <expiration_period>14</expiration_period>
                        <expiration_date>2019-11-29</expiration_date>
                    </order>
                </Row>
            </root>'

            select  
            isnull(a.x.value('(entity/info/cleaned_name)[1]','varchar(max)'),'') as 'Nazwa podmiotu'
            ,isnull(a.x.value('(entity/info/first_name)[1]','varchar(max)'),'') as 'Imię'
            ,isnull(a.x.value('(entity/info/last_name)[1]','varchar(max)'),'') as 'Nazwisko'
            ,isnull(a.x.value('(entity/info/legal_form)[1]','varchar(max)'),'') as 'Forma prawna'
            ,isnull(a.x.value('(entity/info/ownership_type)[1]','varchar(max)'),'') as 'Forma własności'
            ,isnull(a.x.value('(entity/info/commencement_date)[1]','date'),'') as 'Data rozpoczęcia działalności'

            ,isnull(a.x.value('(entity/address/zip_code)[1]','varchar(255)'),'')+' '+isnull(a.x.value('(entity/address/town)[1]','varchar(255)'),'')
            +' '+isnull(a.x.value('(entity/address/street)[1]','varchar(255)'),'')+' '+ISNULL(a.x.value('(entity/address/house_number)[1]','varchar(255)'),'')
            +case when ISNULL(a.x.value('(entity/address/flat_number)[1]','varchar(255)'),'')<>'' then +'/'+a.x.value('(entity/address/flat_number)[1]','varchar(255)')
            else '' end as Adres

            ,isnull(a.x.value('(proceeding/court_name)[1]','varchar(max)'),'') as 'Nazwa sądu'
            ,isnull(a.x.value('(proceeding/court_department)[1]','varchar(max)'),'') as 'Nazwa wydziału'
            ,isnull(a.x.value('(proceeding/signatures)[1]','varchar(max)'),'') as 'Sygnatura'  --grupowanie!
            ,isnull(a.x.value('(proceeding/commissioner_name)[1]','varchar(max)'),'') as 'Sędzia komisarz'
            ,isnull(a.x.value('(proceeding/commissioner_deputy_name)[1]','varchar(max)'),'') as 'Zastępca sędziego komisarza'
            ,isnull(a.x.value('(proceeding/administrator_name)[1]','varchar(max)'),'') as 'Nadzorca w postępowaniu'
            ,isnull(a.x.value('(proceeding/administrator_function)[1]','varchar(max)'),'') as 'Funkcja nadzorcy'

            ,isnull(a.x.value('(order/order_date)[1]','date'),'') as 'Data wydania postanowienia'
            ,isnull(a.x.value('(order/expiration_period)[1]','varchar(20)'),'') as 'Okres do działania (w dniach)'
            ,isnull(a.x.value('(order/expiration_date)[1]','date'),'') as 'Koniec okresu do działania'

            ,isnull(a.x.value('(msig_entry/chapter)[1]','varchar(max)'),'') as 'Rozdział MSiG'
            ,isnull(a.x.value('(msig_entry/section)[1]','varchar(max)'),'') as 'Sekcja MSiG'
            ,isnull(a.x.value('(msig_entry/signature)[1]','varchar(max)'),'') as 'Sygnatura ogłoszenia'
            ,isnull(a.x.value('(msig_entry/issue_date)[1]','date'),'') as 'Data publikacji ogłoszenia w MSiG'

            ,isnull(a.x.value('(content/text)[1]','varchar(max)'),'') as 'Treść ogłoszenia'

            from @xml.nodes('/root/Row') as a(x)
```

My desired result:[image]

Comment: Three hints: Thx for the executable sample, that is a great help, but next time you might reduce it to the needed minimum. And second: Please add the expected output. Your issue is not fully clear... And third: Please tag with your RDBMS (vendor **and version**). `[tsql]` and the code point to `[sql-server]`, but XML support is highly product specific.

Comment: @Shnugo, thx for accurate observations, actually. I've just edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A shorter solution without crossing a tech-border might be this:

```
        ,isnull(STUFF(
                a.x.query('for $s in proceeding/signatures
                           return <x>{concat(",",$s)}</x>')
                   .value('.','varchar(max)'),1,1,''),'') as 'Sygnatura'  --grupowanie!
```

The idea in short:

We re-format the XML-fragment `a.x` using `.query()` in a way, that each signature is returned with a comma in front.

Now we can use `.value()` with a XPath of a simple `'.'`. This will read all the content *in one chunk*.

Finally we need `STUFF` to cut away the leading comma.

### UPDATE

The shortest approach was this actually:

```
,isnull(a.x.query('data(proceeding/signatures)').value('.','varchar(max)'),'') as 'Sygnatura'  --grupowanie!
```

The XQuery-function `data()` will implicitly conactenate the elements and return them separated by a blank. I'd wish for a parameter to define the delimiter, but this is - why ever - not possible. Your problem is, that your signatures include blanks internally. So this will not work for you assumably.

Comment: Great stuff, +1 from my side!

Comment: Shnugo that's absolutely awesome! Could you let me know what $s synthax refers to?

Comment: @Arkadiusz, Besides the issues XQuery was obviously built for, XQuery offers some hacks for string manipulations. To answer your question directly: The `$` is the same as the `@` is in `T-SQL`: It marks a variable. In this case we run through all `<signatures>`. Each node is assigned to `$s`. With this we proceed below. Find details about XQuery-FLWOR [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/flwor-statement-and-iteration-xquery?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @Shnugo, many thx, it looks very useful so I'm gonna familiarize myself with this stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following.

> SQL

```
DECLARE @xml AS XML
= '<root>
        <Row>
            <proceeding>
                <signatures>XII GU 609/18</signatures>
                <signatures>XII GUp 392/18</signatures>
                <commissioner_name></commissioner_name>
                <court_department>XII Wydział Gospodarczy</court_department>
                <administrator_function>syndyk</administrator_function>
                <court_name>Sąd Rejonowy w Gliwicach</court_name>
                <administrator_name></administrator_name>
                <commissioner_deputy_name />
                <administrator_licence_number>920</administrator_licence_number>
            </proceeding>
            <msig_entry>
                <chapter>0</chapter>
                <issue_date>2019-11-15</issue_date>
                <url>http://www.imsig.pl/pozycja/2019/221/58729</url>
                <section>3</section>
                <sequential_number />
                <signature>BMSiG-58674/2019</signature>
                <position_number>58729</position_number>
                <yearly_number>221</yearly_number>
            </msig_entry>
            <entity>
                <info>
                    <first_name></first_name>
                    <last_name></last_name>
                    <legal_form>osoby fizyczne</legal_form>
                    <commencement_date>1954-12-09</commencement_date>
                    <cleaned_name></cleaned_name>
                    <primary_business />
                    <ownership_type>własność</ownership_type>
                </info>
                <address>
                    <town>Jastrzębie-Zdrój</town>
                    <gmina>Jastrzębie-Zdrój</gmina>
                    <house_number />
                    <flat_number />
                    <state>śląskie</state>
                    <street />
                    <post_office>Jastrzębie-Zdrój</post_office>
                    <powiat>Jastrzębie-Zdrój</powiat>
                    <zip_code />
                </address>
            </entity>
            <id>BMSiG-58674/2019</id>
            <order>
                <order_date />
                <expiration_period>14</expiration_period>
                <expiration_date>2019-11-29</expiration_date>
            </order>
        </Row>
    </root>';

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = ',';

SELECT ISNULL(x.value('(entity/info/cleaned_name)[1]', 'varchar(max)'), '') AS 'Nazwa podmiotu',
       ISNULL(x.value('(entity/info/first_name)[1]', 'varchar(max)'), '') AS 'Imię',
       ISNULL(x.value('(entity/info/last_name)[1]', 'varchar(max)'), '') AS 'Nazwisko',
       ISNULL(x.value('(entity/info/legal_form)[1]', 'varchar(max)'), '') AS 'Forma prawna',
       ISNULL(x.value('(entity/info/ownership_type)[1]', 'varchar(max)'), '') AS 'Forma własności',
       ISNULL(x.value('(entity/info/commencement_date)[1]', 'date'), '') AS 'Data rozpoczęcia działalności',
       ISNULL(x.value('(entity/address/zip_code)[1]', 'varchar(255)'), '') + ' '
       + ISNULL(x.value('(entity/address/town)[1]', 'varchar(255)'), '') + ' '
       + ISNULL(x.value('(entity/address/street)[1]', 'varchar(255)'), '') + ' '
       + ISNULL(x.value('(entity/address/house_number)[1]', 'varchar(255)'), '')
       + CASE
             WHEN ISNULL(a.x.value('(entity/address/flat_number)[1]', 'varchar(255)'), '') <> '' THEN
                 +'/' + a.x.value('(entity/address/flat_number)[1]', 'varchar(255)')
             ELSE
                 ''
         END AS Adres,
       ISNULL(x.value('(proceeding/court_name)[1]', 'varchar(max)'), '') AS 'Nazwa sądu',
       ISNULL(x.value('(proceeding/court_department)[1]', 'varchar(max)'), '') AS 'Nazwa wydziału',

    -- grupowanie by Sygnatura
    (SELECT STUFF((SELECT @separator + CAST([Sygnatura] AS VARCHAR(30)) AS [text()]
          FROM (
                SELECT ISNULL(c.value('(./text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), '') AS [Sygnatura]
                FROM @xml.nodes('/root/Row/proceeding/signatures') AS t(c)
          ) AS rs
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, NULL)) AS [Sygnatura_List],

       ISNULL(x.value('(proceeding/commissioner_name)[1]', 'varchar(max)'), '') AS 'Sędzia komisarz',
       ISNULL(x.value('(proceeding/commissioner_deputy_name)[1]', 'varchar(max)'), '') AS 'Zastępca sędziego komisarza',
       ISNULL(x.value('(proceeding/administrator_name)[1]', 'varchar(max)'), '') AS 'Nadzorca w postępowaniu',
       ISNULL(x.value('(proceeding/administrator_function)[1]', 'varchar(max)'), '') AS 'Funkcja nadzorcy',
       ISNULL(x.value('(order/order_date)[1]', 'date'), '') AS 'Data wydania postanowienia',
       ISNULL(x.value('(order/expiration_period)[1]', 'varchar(20)'), '') AS 'Okres do działania (w dniach)',
       ISNULL(x.value('(order/expiration_date)[1]', 'date'), '') AS 'Koniec okresu do działania',
       ISNULL(x.value('(msig_entry/chapter)[1]', 'varchar(max)'), '') AS 'Rozdział MSiG',
       ISNULL(x.value('(msig_entry/section)[1]', 'varchar(max)'), '') AS 'Sekcja MSiG',
       ISNULL(x.value('(msig_entry/signature)[1]', 'varchar(max)'), '') AS 'Sygnatura ogłoszenia',
       ISNULL(x.value('(msig_entry/issue_date)[1]', 'date'), '') AS 'Data publikacji ogłoszenia w MSiG',
       ISNULL(x.value('(content/text)[1]', 'varchar(max)'), '') AS 'Treść ogłoszenia'
FROM @xml.nodes('/root/Row') AS a(x);
```

> Output (abbreviated for clarity)

```
+--------------------------+-------------------------+------------------------------+
|        Nazwa sądu        |     Nazwa wydziału      |        Sygnatura_List        |
+--------------------------+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| Sad Rejonowy w Gliwicach | XII Wydzial Gospodarczy | XII GU 609/18,XII GUp 392/18 |
+--------------------------+-------------------------+------------------------------+
```

Comment: Yitzhak, as you are a FLWOR friend, I just sent a bunch of FLWORs below :-) +1 from my side for this good answer.

Comment: Shnugo, Lol, I did absolutely the same on my machine, but didn't want to post it and confuse Arkadiusz. You and I, we are on the same page. :)